# ExpToTrig conversion problem

Tags: symbolic, complex, trigonometry

Let we have some ODE solution:

```
formExp = c1 E^(-I t) + c2 E^(I t) +c3 E^(-2 I t) + c4 E^(2 I t)
```

It is known that this solution can be reduced to the form:

```
formTrig = k1 Cos[t] + k2 Cos[2 t] + k3 Sin[t] + k4 Sin[2 t]
```

How to make it with Mathematica directly?
I start with

```
ExpToTrig[formExp]  
Output: c1 Cos[t] + c2 Cos[t] + c3 Cos[2 t] + c4 Cos[2 t] - I c1 Sin[t] +
 I c2 Sin[t] - I c3 Sin[2 t] + I c4 Sin[2 t]
```

Next I tried many combinations of `ComplexExpand`, `TrigReduce` etc, but never got `formTrig`.
Is it possible in this way?

Another way is to compare coefficients at the same terms of `formTrig` and `formExp`,
and we immediately get expressions for $k_i$  through $c_i$:

```
k1 == c1+c2 && k2 == c3+c4 && k3 == I (c2-c1) && k4 == I (c4-c3)
```

But how to force Mathematica to do it *automatically*?
I tried

```
Solve[ExpToTrig[formExp] == formTrig , {k1,k2,k3,k4}]
```

Also `Reduce[]` etc. but nothing works (

Comment: Collect[ExpToTrig[formExp], {_Cos, _Sin}] and from output make a comparison. It is not fair to require from Mathematica that it would automatically rename a symbols to the form user wishes.

Comment: Try this one `SolveAlways[
 c1 Cos[t] + c2 Cos[t] + c3 Cos[2 t] + c4 Cos[2 t] - I c1 Sin[t] + 
   I c2 Sin[t] - I c3 Sin[2 t] + I c4 Sin[2 t] == 
  k1 Cos[t] + k2 Cos[2 t] + k3 Sin[t] + k4 Sin[2 t], {Cos[t], Sin[t], 
  Cos[2 t], Sin[2 t]}]`

Comment: @yarchik, thats cool, thanks! For full-automatically solution we need somehow extract list `{Cos[t], Sin[t],    Cos[2 t], Sin[2 t]}` from `formTrig`

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

#### Final solution

Let `linExp` is a arbitrary linear combination of $\exp$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N} c_i  \exp(\alpha_i t)$$
Module `linExpToTrig` accept `linExp` and return:
Closed trigonometric form and needed coefficients substitution  or
"No solution" message if it's not possible

```
Clear[linExpToTrig];
linExpToTrig[linExp_] := 
  Module[{ce = Cases[Level[linExp, {2}], Except@Exp[x_]],
    cft = ExpToTrig@linExp, ft, b, s},
   b = Union@Cases[Level[cft, {2}], Sin[x_] | Cos[x_]];
   ft = b . Table[Subscript[k, j], {j, Length@b}];
   s = Solve[ForAll[Evaluate@b, cft == ft], ce];
   If[s == {}, "No solution",
    <|"TrigForm" -> ft, "Coeffs" -> First@s|>
    ]];
```

#### Tests

```
linExpToTrig[ Subscript[c, 1] E^(-I t) + Subscript[c, 2] E^(I t)]
Output: <|"TrigForm" -> Cos[t] Subscript[k, 1] + Sin[t] Subscript[k, 2], 
 "Coeffs" -> {Subscript[c, 1] -> 
    1/2 (Subscript[k, 1] + I Subscript[k, 2]), 
   Subscript[c, 2] -> 1/2 (Subscript[k, 1] - I Subscript[k, 2])}|>  

linExpToTrig[a E^(-I t) + b E^(I t) + c E^(-2 I t) + d E^(2 I t)]  
Output:
<|"TrigForm" -> 
  Cos[t] Subscript[k, 1] + Cos[2 t] Subscript[k, 2] + 
   Sin[t] Subscript[k, 3] + Sin[2 t] Subscript[k, 4], 
 "Coeffs" -> {a -> 1/2 (Subscript[k, 1] + I Subscript[k, 3]), 
   b -> 1/2 (Subscript[k, 1] - I Subscript[k, 3]), 
   c -> 1/2 (Subscript[k, 2] + I Subscript[k, 4]), 
   d -> 1/2 (Subscript[k, 2] - I Subscript[k, 4])}|>

linExpToTrig[a E^(-2 I t) + b E^(I t) + c E^(-3 I t) + d E^(2 I t)]
Output: No solution
```

#### Ideas

Let we know that `formTrig` is arbitrary linear combination of $\sin$ and $\cos$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N} k_{1,i}  \sin(\alpha_{1,i} t)+ k_{2,i}  \cos(\alpha_{2,i} t)$$

and `formExp` is arbitrary linear combination of $\exp$:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N} c_i  \exp(\alpha_i t)  $$

Firstly we find basis:

```
basis = Last /@ Level[formTrig, {1}]
Output: {Cos[t], Cos[2 t], Sin[t], Sin[2 t]}
```

Than we find list of coefficients of `formExp`:

```
coeffsList = First /@ Level[formExp, {1}]
Output: {c1, c2, c3, c4}
```

and themselves:

```
coeffs = First@Solve[ForAll[Evaluate@basis, ExpToTrig@formExp == formTrig],
  coeffsList]
Output: {c1 -> 1/2 (k1 + I k3), c2 -> 1/2 (k1 - I k3), c3 -> 1/2 (k2 + I k4),
 c4 -> 1/2 (k2 - I k4)}
```

Check it:

```
ComplexExpand[formExp /. coeffs] == formTrig
Output: True
```